# Qlik Sense: how to specify path in Google Drive?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a Google drive account divided into some folders (say, Folder1, Folder2, etc.), with some subfolders in it.
I successfully managed to connect my Qlik Sense app to it.
I need to make it look for files only in a given subfolder.

At the moment, I read as follows ([...] is the location)

```
(URL IS [[...]connectorID=GoogleDriveConnector&table=ListSpreadsheets&appID=], qvx);
```

It works and reloads successfully, but I need it to filter the Spreadsheets properly.
 How could I get what I need?

Comment: Hi did my answer solved problem?

Comment: Actually, no, beacause that's what I already have. The point is the following step to get what I need.

Comment: "filter the Spreadsheets properly" - mean what exactly for example. When you make ListSpreadsheets it create table with Spreadsheets and then it is possible to filter it using table operations (WHERE, JOINS, EXIST etc.)

Answer (score 0):

To connect to Google Drive in fact you use web connector. Once web connector is installed it can be initialized as service or manually from its folder.

Once it i installed (recent version can be downloaded from https://qliksupport.force.com/apex/QS_Home_Page but it seems that you've got it as Google Drive is part of it ) it is much nicer to configure connection to online drives there.

You just go to http://localhost:5555/web and generate ready code.

[image]

In my implementation I used following options step by step to get data which I wanted:

1) CanAuthenticate to generate permanent token
2) ListSpreadsheets
3) ListWorksheets
4) GetWorksheet

Answer (score 0):

You can't just specify path. But it's possible to retrieve the path from QWC services. Please use algorithm like that:

1. Use tables like ListFiles/ListWorksheets
2. Iter through every row with 'for' cycle:

   FOR i=0 to (NoOfRows('Google_ListWorksheets')-1);

   ```
      Let vWorksheetKey = Peek('worksheetKey', $(i), 'Google_ListWorksheets');
      Let vTitle = left(Peek('title', $(i), 'Google_ListWorksheets'),3);
   ```
3. Using 'if' statement find desired folder id/worksheet key by its name (stored in vTitle  variable) and use it:

   load * FROM [$(vQwcConnectionName)]
   (URL IS [http://localhost:5555/data?connectorID=GoogleDriveConnector&table=GetWorksheet&worksheetKey=$(vWorksheetKey)&appID=], qvx);

At the end you will get your files by their location.